# How To Connect Two Domain

Tags: php

I have a question. For example i have two domain:

1. www.1.com (Php, MySQL, code, etc).
2. www.2.com (Files for download).

Now how can i connect this two websites together?

> How want I do?
>   I want this : how can I connect this two domain for "Call" www.2.com from 
>   www.1.com to download/upload files without access in www.2.com
>   I draw a picture for good understanding (sorry for my bad english).

[Connect Two Domains ( Image )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QT3W.png)

Comment: Without access to the second website, you can't. This is called the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You wouldn't like it if I would be able to just upload anything to your server without your permission either.

Comment: websites are mine ( both ),

Comment: are they on the same server?

Comment: In that case you should read up on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). It explains in detail how to setup Cross Origin HTTP Requests.

Comment: thanks guys it's so helpful:*

Comment: `1.com` sends a `curl` or `file_get_contents` to `2.com` with a secure key. `2.com` serves the contents only when that key is present. `1.com` then serves that content however it should.

Comment: if both domains are on the same server, you should be able to just specify the upload dir ("../../2.com/public_html/") bear in mind that the directory in 2.com should be writable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) from php.  cURL can do so many things, so you can probably google "php curl upload" or something the get more specific answers.  But the key-word you are looking for is probably cURL.

Please note that if you are going server-to-server, CORS will not make any difference -- CORS only affects client-to-server.

Comment: yes, i googled it and that is i want.
www.1.com => say to : www.2.com
"hello my request is get this file and save that to this directory : /files/upload/" and then www.2.com say : ok!